# Why I am unable to open a file RW with CreateFile Win32 API but can remove it with std::remove?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, stl

My C++ application runs in Windows 10 under user **`SYSTEM`**. I try to open a **readonly** file with Win32 api CreateFile using access permission `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE`, getting an `INVALID_HANDLER_VALUE` from the function call.

However, the same program is able to remove said file using a simple call to `std::remove()`.

My guess is that functions from C standard library doesn't check user access permissions and lets you freely access the FS from whatever execution level your program has, but I'm not 100% convinced and can't find evidence of this online.

Any OS / STL guru is able to solve this little riddle?

Comment: 'My guess is that STL doesn't check user access permissions' - it doesn't have any choice, (I hope!).  Such permissions/privileges are enforced by the underlying OS.

Comment: This particular `remove` comes from the C Standard Library, not STL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows has specific `DELETE` permissions (not relevant for FAT filesystems, but natively implemented on NTFS). These are independent from `WRITE` permissions. Permissions might exist on the file itself or be inherited from the parent (i.e. directory).

On Unix and Linux, things are slightly different; files deletes are handled there via write permissions on the parent directory.

Comment: not need (and not enough) write permission on the directory. need or exactly `DELETE` permission on file or `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` on parent folder

Comment: on windows look this [`FsdCheckDeleteFileAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/irp-mj-set-information3) - file system first check for `DELETE` access on target file. if it exist - all ok, we can delete (except file is read-only, or section created on file). if we have no `DELETE` access on target. file system do additional check on parent folder for `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` access. if exist - again grant delete. and exist several delete file ways. only for `ZwDeleteFile` this is enough

Comment: From [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx): "If a user has full control over a folder, the user can delete files in the folder regardless of the permission on the files."
And, I forgot to mention that the target FS was FAT, didn't actually know it was relevant.

Comment: @phagio - not need full access. required and enough `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` exactly. of course if file not write-protected and not in use

Comment: @RbMm, getting just delete access is enough for WinAPI `DeleteFile`. At first it tries to get both delete and read-attributes access, which will succeed if the access is allowed on the file or if the parent directory allows delete-child and list-directory (for read-attributes) access. If it can't get read-attributes access, it tries again with just delete access -- in which case it will never follow any reparse points, whereas normally it wants read-attributes access to avoid following only symbolic-link reparse points.

Comment: @MSalters, could you change the wording to "obtained from the parent" instead of "inherited from the parent"? It's not actually inherited. The filesystem has to separately evaluate the access check on the parent directory to check for delete-child access.

Comment: @eryksun: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx) uses "inherited", I'd call that authoritative.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, you right and have perfect knowledge :) however `DeleteFile` anyway restricted on not directory files only. and i be prefer do only one call to kernel, instead 3 or 4 in case `DeleteFile`

Comment: @MSalters, delete access and delete-child access can be inherited from the parent directory to files and subdirectories, but that's unrelated to evaluating delete-child access on the parent to check for delete access on a file. This is important if you're manually evaluating access via `AccessCheck`. It's not enough to just get the security descriptor of the file; you may also have to get the parent's security and do a second `AccessCheck`.